Is it possible to find a closed form for $i!$?
I am curious is there a closed form for $i!$? I tried to search for any closed form for this but I didn't find any.
$$z! := \lim_{n \to \infty } n^z \prod_{k=1}^n \frac {k}{z+k}$$
$$i! =\lim_{n \to \infty } n^i \prod_{k=1}^n \frac {k}{i+k}$$
$$i+k = \sqrt{1+k^2} e^{i\arctan \frac{1}{k}}$$
$$i! = \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{n^i n!}{e^{i\left(\arctan 1+\arctan\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\arctan\frac{1}{n-1}+\arctan\frac{1}{n}\right)} } \prod_{k=1}^n \frac {1}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}  $$

One also could calculate $i!$ using $z=|z|e^{i\arg(z)}$. $|i!|$ has an elementary closed form, but $\arg(i!)$ does not seem to have one

Seems that it would be $|i!|^2 = \pi/\sinh(\pi)$ from the properties of $\Gamma$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General
